# Paging, sorting and filtering on multiple libraries in a site collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, search, jsom

I have 10 document libraries sharing a common content type say `'contenttype1'`. I want to have a page where I would list all the columns as filters to the users if the user selects any value for a column.

We should show all the documents from those 10 document libraries matching the properties selected.

Please tell me the best way to achieve this.

Is there any out of the box search options available. The number of documents in each library will be huge.

Kindly suggest me the best way to approach this? I would like to list the results in a grid format (like providing the link of documents from the search result) and would also want to implement paging and sorting on the search results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you are using either SharePoint 2013 or SPO.

If you can only use "out of the box" methods, I would start with a Result Source that filters on "ContentType=contenttype1". This would limit the result to only that content type from any library. (If you want to limit to only your 10 libraries then you'd have to add the Paths to the query, but that is ugly and not a great solution. Stick with Content Type.)

Next create a Search results page and set the query parameter to use your Result Source. Now this page will only list the results from your content type.

The next step is to make your properties filterable (we say "refinable"). Since you are using a Content Type you have site columns for your metadata, what you need to do is create (or associate) the crawled properties with refinable properties in the Search Schema section of the site. For each property you wish to refine on you need a matching Refinable (and/or sortable) property.

Once a full crawl has run and your refinable properties are populated, return to your search page and edit the Refinement web part. Add your refinable properties and save the web part, the page and publish.

Test your query.

If you need detailed steps I have used key words in this post that you can use to Bing (or Google) your way to success. Add a comment if you need clarification.

Answer (score 1):

No OOB Way. You should create a custom web part to retrieve all documents form those 10 document, then filter and sort them.

To retrieve all items from libraries in a web site, you can refer the following article. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee534956(v=office.14).aspx#sectionSection4

To get specific libraries, you also need add conditions to the logic to check if the library is what you want.